# Qualifier annotation method not finding beans as a Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, autowired

The below works fine, the problem is i need this to run before another bean that will use some of the resources created here. When I change `@Component` to `@Configuration` I get an error `Cannot find bean with qualifier localSNS`

```
@Component
public class ResourceCreation {

    String queueUrl;

    @Qualifier("localSNS")
    @Autowired
    AmazonSNS amazonSNS;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are creating the AmazonSNS bean with that qualifier?

Comment: Yea, it works fine with component only i get an error from my bean saying topic doesnt exist. I am using testcontainers

Comment: Is it possible, that "localSNS" isn't available at all? Try using constructor injection instead of field injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate class with `@DependsOn`

> FileProcessor specifies its dependencies with @DependsOn. We can also annotate a Component with @DependsOn:
>
> ```
> @Component
> @DependsOn({"filereader", "fileWriter"})
> ```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work with the qualifier annotation as the variables inside my class are still nulll

Comment: @anonymousalias without change `@Component` to `@Configuration`?